# PHP 5 windows install problem: http://localhost/info.php

Tags: php, installation, phpinfo

I downloaded the php-5.3.3-Win32-VC6-x86.msi file from php's download page. I have a working apache2 server running. On the setup window I selected the apache 2.2.x Module and on the Apache Configuration directory I selected the conf file.

The info.php page isn't appearing on my browser (404 Not Found), why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is Apache set up properly?  In other words, are you just getting the PHP code in your browser?

Comment: Apache is working properly. The "It Works" page appears when I write http://localhost on the browser bar. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: What does "isn't appearing on my browser" mean?

Comment: means 404 Not Found

Comment: Did you put your php code in the directory where Apache is looking for them?

Comment: What php code? I haven't written any php code, http://localhost/info.php page should appear according to the installation instructions that I'm following. Do I have to tell Apache where is the php folder I've installed? How?

Comment: @dmindreader, Place some PHP files on your web root and navigate to it.

Answer (score 1):

sorry I would leave this as a comment but I can't:
if you don't need version 5.3.3 and version 5.3.1 is fine too then I'd suggest that you stick with [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) which does all the setup work for you